# What licence should I use for my portfolio website?

Tags: licensing

I'm a computer scientist. I would want to show the projects I've made along the years, my curriculum vitae and the good points that some of my former customers and employers have written about my project and myself.

What licence should I display in the footer of my website?

I think I don't want MIT or something else that would be open-source. I would rather prefer a proprietary licence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What licence should I display in the footer of my website?

None unless you want people to copy and reuse the content.

The content (except for mere facts) will be protected by copyright regardless. When you expect people to want to copy and reuse it, it makes sense to tell them in advance under what conditions they can do it (instead of being bothered by their questions). This is what displaying a licence is for.

If you were a visual designer then a licence would make sense as visuals are likely to be wanted to be copied and used. But a CV, list of projects and comments from customers are probably not likely to be wanted for reuse and distribution, though it is ultimately for you to decide.

If you think someone will want to copy and further distribute your content, you'll need to figure out under what conditions you want to allow it, and then search for a licence that fits. If none found, just create your own.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! Taking into account your answer, I would like to display the information "There is no license" for aesthetic reasons. What ready-made phrase should I use?  Is there a "license" for cases where there is no license? If so, I could mention it.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler "there is no license" is misleading. "This code is copyrighted." is less misunderstandable.